# How to disable ldap failed authentication message from audit.logs

Tags: server, authentication, pam, ldap

I have to disable LDAP user failed PAM authentication messages from `audit.logs`

**`/var/log/audit.log | grep failed`**

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1660931213.045:2190121): pid=289 uid=0 auid=4294965 ses=4297295 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="duser" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=179.X.X.X1 addr=179.X.X.X1 terminal=ssh res=failed'
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1660912303.25:2191216): pid=289 uid=0 auid=4294965 ses=4297295 msg='op=login acct="duser" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=179.X.X.X1 terminal=sshd res=failed'
```

I am getting two entries of failed messages for the single attempt, I don't need these 2 entries, one entry is enough to know the failed attempt from the system, So now I want to disable the PAM module failure entry,
So, please suggest an PAM configuration to disable the log entries.
Thanks

*Asghar.A*

Answer (score 1):

To exclude either of the 2 messages (or both) you can do this:

```
sudo auditctl -a exclude,never -F msgtype=USER_AUTH
sudo auditctl -a exclude,never -F msgtype=LOGIN
```

See the manual page of [auditctl](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) for more examples. The `-a` and the 2 options used:

> **-a [list,action|action,list]**
>
> Append rule to the end of list with action. Please note the comma separating the two values. Omitting it will cause errors. The fields may be in either order. It could be list,action or action,list. The following describes the valid list names:

> **exclude**
>
> Add a rule to the event type exclusion filter list. This list is used to filter events that you do not want to see. For example, if you do not want to see any avc messages, you would using this list to record that. The message type that you do not wish to see is given with the msgtype field.

> **never**
>
> No audit records will be generated. This can be used to suppress event generation. In general, you want suppressions at the top of the list instead of the bottom. This is because the event triggers on the first matching rule.

> **-F [n=v | n!=v | n<v | n>v | n<=v | n>=v | n&v | n&=v]**
>
> Build a rule field: name, operation, value. You may have up to 64 fields passed on a single command line. Each one must start with -F

> **msgtype**
>
> This is used to match the event's record type. It should only be used on the exclude filter list.